# Text decoration underline on link but not on ::before?

Tags: html, css-selectors, font-awesome, pseudo-element

How can I get the link to have a **underline** but the (fontawesome) icon `::before` not? `::before text decoration:none;` doesn't work

```css
.btn--tertiary {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-left: 0;
    color: #007e9e;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 0 solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-flex !important;
}

.btn--tertiary::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f0a9";
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #9cc923;
}
div {
    width: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
<a href="#" class="btn--tertiary">Test link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn--tertiary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using position absolute

```html
<div>
<style>
  .btn--tertiary {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #007e9e;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 0 solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-flex !important;
  }

  .btn--tertiary::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f0a9";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #9cc923;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
<link
  href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<link
  href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<a href="#" class="btn--tertiary">Test link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn--tertiary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ah wait, I forgot to add there is also a `display:inline-flex` on `btn--tertiary` I did edit my original post, sadly then `display:inline-block` doesnt work

Comment: You added that in parent, I added display in icon

Comment: Yes, it was there before I made the post, I just forgot to add it in the snippet.
When adding `display:inline-block` to the icon it doesn't work with `inline-flex` on the parent

Comment: Yeap, child with inline-block deosn't work in parent with inline-flex. Is the `inline-flex` still necessary? If you remove that, inline-block can work fine in removing underline

Comment: KasRoudra, i edited my original post with an example, with `display:inline-block` it would not jump in behind the icon anymore

Comment: Okay, I've now fixed it with position absolute. Check if it meets your requirenment

Comment: Almost, but how can I keep the links both under each other?

Comment: You can place those links in a parent div with style `style="display: flex; flex-direction:column"`

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the underline from the anchor-element. This way your font-awesome icon (which is part of the anchor-element) won't be underlined as well. If you do want the rest of the text-underlined you could use a span-element for that.

```css
.underline{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn--tertiary {
    text-decoration: none!important;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-left: 0;
    color: #007e9e;
    border: 0 solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-flex !important;
}

.btn--tertiary::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f0a9";
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #9cc923;
}

div {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <a href="#" class="btn--tertiary"><span class="underline">Test link 1</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="btn--tertiary"><span class="underline">Lorem ipsum.</span></a>
</div>
```